# How to use the generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, methods, types

How to change to generic method, and us it.

I have method like this :

```
        private void CompaniesList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CompaniesWindow comapaniesWindow = Container.Resolve<CompaniesWindow>();
            comapaniesWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
        private void UsersList(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UsersWindow usersWindow = Container.Resolve<UsersWindow>();
            usersWindow.Show();
        }
        private void NewCompany(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CompanyWindow companyWindow = Container.Resolve<CompanyWindow>();
            companyWindow.Show();
        }
```

I want to use a generic method like this:

```
        private void ShowWindow<T>(T type) where T: Window
        {
            var _window = Container.Resolve<type>();
            _window.ShowDialog();
        }
```

And us it like this :

```
ShowWindow(ToolsWindow)
```

Comment: Can you please confirm if you're calling `ShowDialog` ? Or are you calling both `ShowDialog` and `Show`. If you're calling only `ShowDialog` please update your question.

Comment: Just put the `T` inside the resolve call `Container.Resolve<T>()` and remove `T type` from your method signature. Then use `ShowWindow<ToolsWindow>()`

Comment: @RafałBędkowski I don't understand the nature of the question because if you know how to do that for `Resolve` you know how to do that for `ShowWindow` as answered below... Is there a subtility ? And if so could you improve and clarify the question, please ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier typically `Container.Resolve<T>`  is a function to retrieve a service, maybe he is using the Unity container,  a lightweight, extensible dependency injection container.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void ShowDialog<T>() where T : Window
{
    var window = Container.Resolve<T>();
    window.ShowDialog();
}

public void Show<T>() where T : Window
{
    var window = Container.Resolve<T>();
    window.Show();
}
```

Comment: (The ShowWindow call is missing)

Comment: I have not used `ShowWindow` because he is using 3 different functions. I send a question but he is not responding. Anyway, the user can ser any name to the functions I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void ShowWindow<T>() where T : Window
        {
            var _window = Container.Resolve<T>();
            _window.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Then call using

```
ShowWindow<ToolsWindow>();
```